# Invariant Violation: The navigation prop is missing for this navigator. In react-navigation v3 and v4 you must set up your app container directly

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

I am a beginner on React and am working on a project but I could not pass this error, I looked through similar topics, but still couldn't fix the problem, I will be glad if you guys help me!

---

> ERROR    Invariant Violation: The navigation prop is missing for this
> navigator. In react-navigation v3 and v4 you must set up your app
> container directly. More info:
> https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/app-containers.html This error is
> located at:
> in Navigator (at MainComponent.js:81)
> in RCTView (at View.js:34)
> in View (at MainComponent.js:80)
> in Main (at App.js:7)
> in App (at renderApplication.js:45)
> in RCTView (at View.js:34)
> in View (at AppContainer.js:106)
> in RCTView (at View.js:34)
> in View (at AppContainer.js:132)
> in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:39)

---

**MainComponent.js**

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Menu from './MenuComponent';
import Home from './HomeComponent';
import Dishdetail from './DishdetailComponent';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation-drawer';
import { DISHES } from '../shared/dishes';


const MenuNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Menu: { screen: Menu },
  Dishdetail: { screen: Dishdetail }
},
{
  initialRouteName: 'Menu',
  navigationOptions: {
      headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: "#512DA8"
      },
      headerTintColor: '#fff',
      headerTitleStyle: {
          color: "#fff"            
      }
  }
}
);

const HomeNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: Home }
}, {
  navigationOptions: {
    headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: "#512DA8"
    },
    headerTitleStyle: {
        color: "#fff"            
    },
    headerTintColor: "#fff"  
  }
});

const MainNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
  Home: 
    { screen: HomeNavigator,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: 'Home',
        drawerLabel: 'Home'
      }
    },
  Menu: 
    { screen: MenuNavigator,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: 'Menu',
        drawerLabel: 'Menu'
      }, 
    }
}, {
drawerBackgroundColor: '#D1C4E9'
});

class Main extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      dishes: DISHES,
      selectedDish: null
    };
  }
  onDishSelect(dishId) {
    this.setState({selectedDish: dishId})
}

  render() {
 
    return (
      <View style={{flex:1, paddingTop: 10}}>
            <MainNavigator />
        </View>
    );
  }
}
  
export default Main;
```

This is the Error SS:

[image]

Comment: are you using which react-natigation version

Comment: "name": "react-navigation",
 "version": "4.4.3",

 "name": "react-navigation-stack",
 "version": "2.10.2",

 "name": "react-navigation-drawer",
 "version": "2.6.0",

Comment: you are doing in wrong way

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is not the lastest version of react-navigation that you are using if you are starting a new app trying to use a newer version which is the `v5.x.x`,

To fix the above error, according to docs You have to wrap your navigators with `createAppContainer` explicitly
[Link to docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/app-containers/#props-of-createappcontainer-on-react-native)

try to wrap your navigators like this.

```
const MenuNavigatorContainer = createAppContainer(MenuNavigator)
const HomeNavigatorContainer = createAppContainer(HomeNavigator)
const MainNavigator Container = createAppContainer(MainNavigator)
```

and use these new containers instead of navigators.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing that in wrong way, you cant directly declare the `drawer` as React component

```
const MyApp = createAppContainer(MainNavigator);
```

and after that add a reference to render method

```
<View style={{flex:1, paddingTop: 10}}>
    <MyApp />
</View>
```

Comment: If you like my answer or you got any help from my answer, don't forget to consider up-vote and check this answer as the best answer for you by clicking on the right arrow, thanks!